# Failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NOT_INITILIZED: initialization error when I execute codes in Jupyter notebook , and the GPU isn't being used

Tags: tensorflow, cuda, gpu

The job can finished successfully on CPUs, but none of GPU is being used When I execute codes in JupyterNotebook, and the console of Jupyter show a error message：Failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NOT_INITILIZED: initialization error.

Here is the hardware and software information:

1. OS: I tried to run the codes in Ubuntu180403 ppc64le and RHEL76, 
   none of OS can run Job on GPU
2. CUDA ： 10.1.243
3. GPU Driver： 418.87.00
4. CUDA Toolkit : 10.1
5. TensorFlow: 14.01a, actually it's includes in IBM powerai CE 1.6.1
6. Hardware: AC922, 4 * GPU is nvidia V100

I tried to execute a CNN train job, or just try to find local devices by following codes and only CPU is listed.

```py
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib as _device_lib
_device_lib.list_local_devices()
```

The console of Jupyter notebook show the following error:

```
[tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:318] 
Failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NOT_INITILIZED: initialization error
[tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagonostics.cc:169] 
Retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: powerai
[tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagonostics.cc:176] 
hostname: powerai 
[tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagonostics.cc:200] 
libcuda reported version is : 418.87.0
[tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagonostics.cc:204] 
kernel reported version is : 418.78.0
[tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagonostics.cc:310] 
kernel version seems to match BSO: 418.87.0
```

After that, I tried to check if the CUDA is good by run a CUDA example, and the CUDA throw the floowing error:

```
$ sudo ./deviceQuery
./deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

cudaGetDeviceCount returned 3
-> initialization error
Result = FAIL
```

Comment: Hi Lee, Is the ./deviceQuery command being run on bare metal or a container? It doesn't seem like that nvidia driver is loaded. Can you post the output of `dkms status`, and can you use `rpm -qa | grep kernel` to ensure kernel, kernel-headers, and kernel-devel versions all match. Also does `service nvidia-persistenced status` show the status as running?

Comment: Thanks a lot for William helping! The command ./deviceQuery on a bare metal machine. 
I already run the folloiwng commands to update the kernel before I install CUDA and GPU Driver:
(1) yum update kernel kernel-devel kernel-tools kernel-tools-libs kernel-bootwrapper;yum update; reboot on RHEL76
(2) sudo apt-get install linux-header-$(uname -r); reboot on Uuntu180403

I will run these commands provided by you when I go to client office tomorrow morning.

Comment: Note , a post to https://developer.ibm.com/answers/topics/powerai/, would get the attention of more PowerAI developers.

Answer (score 1):

On PPC RHEL, a number of configuration steps are required for GPU usage, documented in the [product documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS5SF7_1.6.1/navigation/welcome.html):
* Setup of **udev** rules
* Configuration of **nvidia-persistenced** service

You can also reference [Troubleshooting NVIDIA GPU driver issues](https://medium.com/@andrewlaidlawpower/troubleshooting-nvidia-gpu-driver-issues-624ecff9852b).

Issues with GPU access can also result from SELinux setting on the Nvidia devices.  Try turning off SELinux temporarily (`setenforce 0`) to see if this resolves the issue.  If so, run

```
  restorecon -v -R /usr/
  restorecon -v -R /dev/
```

and activate SELinux again, hopefully this fixes the issue.

Lastly, on Power9 systems there is a known race condition, see [What to do with “cudaSuccess (3 vs. 0) initialization error” on a POWER9 system?](https://developer.ibm.com/linuxonpower/2019/10/07/what-to-do-with-cudasuccess-3-vs-0-initialization-error-on-a-power9-system/).

Answer (score -1):

Some possibilities:

1. Could you confirm if the GPU is being used (or available) before running your code ?
2. Do you have permission to submit job running with GPU (if your setup is based on job-based system) ?

Comment: Thank kursun for your help firstly!

We can monitor GPU by command "watch nvidia-smi" when execute codes in jupyter notebook, I can find no any process in GPUs. 

Yes,  I have permission because I start Jupyter notebook by root of RHEL OS or execute ubuntu commands by "sudo ..."

Comment: No, we didn't, we are still struggling on it.